# mongoose - how to validate specific fields only?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nodes, mean-stack

I have following mongoose model and routing file.

> user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId,

    var userSchema = new Schema({
        nick_name: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        },
        first_name: String,
        last_name: String,
        birth_date: {
             type: Date 
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            select: true
        },
        user_type: {
            type: Number,
        },
        is_active: {
            type: Number,
            default: -1
        }
    }, { collection: 'user' });


/*
 *Validations
 */
userSchema.path('nick_name').required(true, 'nick name is required!');
userSchema.path('email').required(true, 'email is required!');
userSchema.path('password').required(true, 'password is required!');
userSchema.path('user_type').required(true, 'user type is required!');
userSchema.path('is_active').required(true, 'is active is required!');
userSchema.path('is_close').required(true, 'is close is required!');


userSchema.path('first_name').required(true, 'first name is required!');
userSchema.path('last_name').required(true, 'last name is required!');
userSchema.path('birth_date').required(true, 'birth date is required!');

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

> router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
router
    .route('/api/user/register')
    .post(
        function(req, res, next) {
            var user_ = new User(req.body);
            /*
             *here all validations are required
             */
            user_.validate(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.json({ "status": 0, "error": err });
                    } else {
                        user_.save(function(err) {
                            if (err) {
                                res.json({ "status": 0, "error": { "other": "Oops! something went wrong, please try again later." } });
                            } else {
                                res.json({ error: 1, message: 'User registered' });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
    }
});
```

In above routing file I can validate all fields by using validate() method but, I have need validation as following conditions

->When user register, following fields are required
 nick_name
 email
 password
 user_type
 is_active
->When user edit his profile (after register), all fields are required.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I just found myself in this situation, want to update a comment model and want a specific field validation for field 'content'.

Im thinking about a hack, pull off that full comment document from the database, then create a new schema object with the same properties from the comment document that i just pulled off from the database and validate this document model copy as if i were to create a new document, but i wont, i wont use the save() method. If there is an error with the 'content' field, which is the only one i care, i would know after validation, if there is no errors then i forget about that new object schema copy that i created by pulling off the comment document from the database, ill forget about it since i already know my 'content' field is valid since no errors where shown, so ill proceed with my flow.

Perhaps instead of pulling off that document from the database i can just create a new object with some fake but valid fields... Then pass the real value i want to test which in my case is 'content', i wouldnt fake that value since i already have it.

NOTE: my comment model has property 'createdAt' so i would replace that for the current date, cause i could have errors at validation saying new comment must be from current date and no from past dates, but since i wont be saving that new date to the database i can add the current date, recall that i will forget about that new object, i wont save it to the database, all i care is the 'content' field validation and see if there is any errors.

Comment: Thank you for answering. As it is, this answer is poorly formatted, making it very hard to read and understand. Always take a look at your post in the preview section before posting. Is the code properly [marked and indented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262)? Did you use enough paragraphs and [other formatting tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)? Please [edit] your post until it is easy to read and understand. Also read the article on [answer]. Well formatted answers will get you more upvotes and have a higher chance of being accepted.